# I need to get a text without tags in my HTML, using xpath

Tags: c#, .net, xpath

I can get to the tag, the problem is that I cant get the text right after the tag.

I've already tried:

```
y.SelectSingleNode($"td[5]/font/b[.='{labelCampo}']")
y.SelectSingleNode($"td[5]/font/b[.='{labelCampo}']/text()").InnerText
```

And many other forms.

```
<td align="left" width="623">

<font class="normal">

<b>Protocolo:</b>

"850160251675 (09/11/2016)"
<br>
```

I want to get this number and date and not the text "Protocolo:"

```
enter code here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it!

I just needed to use the `.Nextsibiling.innertext` in my original statement

```
y.SelectSingleNode($"td[5]/font/b[.='{labelCampo}']").NextSibling.InnerText
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select "normal" class and use innerText attribute to take number and date.

I have tried this code and it's totally work.

```
var html =
    @"<html>
    <body><p>
    <table class=\'foo\'>
        <tr><th>hello</th></tr>
        <tr><td>world</td></tr>
    </table>
    <div class=\'test\'>
        <b>Protocolo:</b>
        850160251675 (09/11/2016)
        </div>
    </body></html>";

    var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

    var body = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[contains(@class, 'test')]");

    Console.WriteLine(body.InnerText);
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/d4chXg

Comment: The problem is that I need to parse more fields and there are lots of fields with the class normal, however thanks for your help